# Cant Delete item from flatlist

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to delete an item from my flat list by touching it, but I am unable to do so. I understand that I need to pass the touched index to my `deleteMessage()` function, but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
deleteMessage(item) {
    console.log("delete message!");
    console.log(item);
    index = this.state.messageList.indexOf(item);
    console.log(index);
    let newList = this.state.messageList.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(newList);
    this.setState({
      messageList: newList

    });
  }

  renderMessage(message) {
    console.log(message.item);
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> this.deleteMessage()}>
        <Text style={styles.message}> {message.item} </Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList  
          style={styles.listContainer}
          data={this.state.messageList}
          renderItem={item => this.renderMessage(item)}
        />
        <View style={styles.sendContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.TextInputStyle}
            onChangeText={text => this.handleInputMessage(text)}
            placeholder="type message here"
            value={this.state.message}
          />
          <Button onPress={() => this.handleSubmitMessage()} title="sennd" />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
deleteMessage(item) {
    var messageList = [...this.state.messageList]
    let index = messageList.indexOf(item);
    messageList.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ messageList });
}
```

`...` is called [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), in the above code, it copies the `this.state.messageList` array. Therefore, when you make any changes to it, you're changing what's in `messageList` array instead of `this.state.messageList` array

The problems in your code are that:

1. You are mutating state by calling `.splice()` directly on `this.state.messageList`
2. `.splice()` returns the deleted item(s), not the remaining items, therefore, after you call `.splice()` on your state, you new list contains only the items that you had deleted

Have fun!

Comment: Could you be a good buddy and accept the answer if it solves your problem please?